# Equivalent asp Chr() for java

Tags: java, asp.net

How to create `Chr("&H" & "0D")` in java

I need to use these characters as a separation so that they can be read by an exe file.

In ASP I'd do as follows: `Chr("&H" & "0D")`
How would I pass it into java?

```
Dim strSplit
strSplit = Chr("&H" & "0D")
Response.Write("Code=0" & strSplit & "CMoney=500000" & strSplit & "CNFlag=0" & strSplit)
```

in Java

```
private final char cc = (char) 0D;
public String isClanMember(){
    return "Code=2"+c+"CName=ClanTeste"+c+"CNote=Revanche Clans"+c+"CZang=xCaD"+c+"CStats=1"+c+"CMCnt=1"+c+"CIMG=1000000001"+c+"CSec=60"+c+"CRegiD=24/07/2015 ¿ÀÈÄ 20:24:44"+c+"CLimitD=01/06/2025 ¿ÀÈÄ 20:24:44"+c+"CDelActive=0"+c+"CPFlag=0"+c+"CKFlag=0"+c+"CMoney=0"+c+"CNFlag=0";
}
```

Comment: What would be the result of the above with asp?

Comment: the browser displays as space, but for the executable has significant value.

Comment: **What** value? And what **significance**? And why would it have the same *unspecificed significance* in Java? What are you trying to do? This (as written) is another [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243725).

Comment: An executable of a game read data coming from a asp page, such data are printed this way: `KEY=VALUE@KEY2=VALUE` (@ is `Chr ("& H" & "0D")`)
I could do this: `char cc = (char) 13` and the data printed out one to a line, however the game still can not identify because lack `&H`

Comment: Have you tried `String str="KEY=VALUE@KEY2=VALUE";`? I have no idea what you're asking otherwise...

Comment: I believe it is difficult to understand, but what I need is this
[functional example asp](http://177.223.0.68:8012/ServerMain/isClanMember.asp?userid=jricardo&gserver=LAB&chname=xCaD&ticket=500)

It appears to be a single space, but is actually `Chr ("& H" & "0D")`, which is among the data

Answer (score 0):

char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

forDigit(int digit, int radix)
Determines the character representation for a specific digit in the specified radix.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

So Character.forDigit(97,10) should return 'a'